# How to reproduce error run out of disk?

Tags: java, testing, io

I am reproducing some issues to test my code. It should tolerate some network issues like `connection rest` and IO issues like `out of space`.

How can I reproduce the issue `out of space`?

Update 1: I got the solution. I used a VirtualBox for this testing, just simply attach a small disk to vm, put some dummy data to eat up the space then test my code.

Answer (score 4):

In your unit tests (I'm assuming you have unit tests and you want to reproduce your error in a unit test) you can use a mock instead of the actual file stream you are writing to, and, say, after two or three reads to the stream your mock throws the error.

You can use mockito library to do this.

It would be something like this:

```
FileWriter myStream = mock(FileWriter.class);
when(myStream.write(any())).thenThrow(new ExceptionToThrowException());
// some code...
myObject.setFileWriter(myStream);
// more code ...
```

(the above code is just a guidance, I didn't compile or test it...)

Answer (score 1):

try this . once done kill this java process and then remove the file "D://toberemoved"

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream(new File("D://toberemoved"));
    ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(os);

    while (true) {
        oos.write(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, it helps me to generate dummy file but not actually solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can really simulate out of space. But for the sake of your testing, you may create a temporary partition and can fill it with some junk.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the smallest USB drive you can find, and fill it with a huge text file, or your entire movie or photo collection.

Answer (score 0):

[LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) is your friend if you are on Linux. However, mocking should be better here. Checkout [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito) or [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/).